# Is there a verb opposite to "slow down?"

Tags: word-request

I'm searching for a word that means "accelerate" but should be made of the word "fast" and would be opposite of "slow down." Something like "fast up."

Example:

Insulin *slows down* the breakdown of glycogen.

Insulin *fasts up* the synthesis of glycogen.

If the word "fast" cannot be used, what would be the most appropriate other word, except accelerate, in the above example? "Speed up?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term ***the synthesis of glycogen*** isn't common enough to draw meaningful conclusions by searching NGrams (chart-based interface into the vast Google Books corpus), but [here's what I found](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accelerate%20protein%20synthesis%2Cspeed%20up%20protein%20synthesis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccelerate%20protein%20synthesis%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caccelerate%20protein%20synthesis%3B%2Cc0) using ***protein synthesis***...

[image: Ngram][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCf4O.png)

Maybe it's just that ***to accelerate*** sounds more "professional, academic" than ***to speed up*** (there's certainly no *semantic* difference). But the preference is obviously quite strong, given the latter doesn't even occur often enough to show on the chart.

I didn't bother including ***quicken*** or ***hasten*** as per the other answer here, because they're *so* unlikely. (Not least because nobody talked about "protein synthesis" back in Victorian times when those verbs *might* have been used in similar contexts! :)

But note that in more colloquial / conversational contexts, ***speed up*** is a vastly more common "opposite" to ***slow down*** (which in academia might more often be expressed as ***retard, inhibit***).

---

TLDR: The standard term ***is*** "accelerate". Forget about looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

*speed*, *speed up*, *quicken*, or *hasten* can be used.

Comment: Good answers; OP should note note that *to speed* in that sense can only be used transitively ("speed a process") and never intransitively ("the process is speeding") because the intransitive use is reserved for the sense "to violate the speed limit on a road". (Had a physics teacher who didn't realize that).

Comment: Yes. I'd add that "speed up" is the normal phrase that one would use. The others are valid but mostly out of date, used commonly 100 years ago but not so much today.